# Magic Mouse Wheel

Tags: modeling

So, I've been working around this issue for a long time but now I really need a way to make this work properly since it's taking certain functions from my reach.

I use a magic mouse from Apple, and have both the 3 button emulation and 3D view presets corrected in User Preferences. However, when it comes to actually needing to scroll the wheel as a means for numeric selection, it simply doesn't work. For instance, after click ctrl+b (bevel) and potentially using the wheel to set the number of segments. Same thing happens with creating loopcuts for example.

I find it so strange that I couldn't find anyone referring to this problem but I'm hoping there's a quick solution out there and this is very frustating since in the case of bevelling I can't even find a keyboard alternative.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a mousewheel, you can use the - and + on the numpad. Hit ctrl-B, draw the bevel and hit - or + to add or substract. This also works for adding ring-cuts and to make the size of the Proportional Editing bigger/smaller. I work with Mac and use a Wacom-pen so i use this and works well. Just give it a try, hope this helps for you as well.

Comment: Thank you. However my keyboard doesn't have a numpad, I have the emulation turned on, which leaves me with no idea where the + or - end up. I tried the default + plus but it didn't work...

Comment: I believe that you then have to press fn-key and +key. Default doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

go to your user preferences - input - seek and change the bind of every thing that uses wheel up or wheel down.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/69396)

Comment: why its doesnt i told him where to change the shorcuts?!

Comment: @MichaelBenDavid SE sites have a review system, _This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content_  Consider if  the user has never changed a shortcut / keymap.